# Is there any Stack Exchange site for career advice?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question, I posted that on one site, but they consider it more of a career advice question. I am unable to find if there any site of this type?

Answer (score 2):

I think questions asking for career advice are likely to be closed for seeking opinion-based answers on most Stack Exchange sites.

There is an exception as commented by @Oded:

> Depends on the advice - [The
>   Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) is all about
>   "navigating the workplace", so some careers advice fits (as usual -
>   read their [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting).

You may find that career advice questions are fine to ask in some Stack Exchange chat rooms but check the site's Meta if you do not see such questions being asked and answered in a chat room because they may not be allowed there either.

I know that GIS career advice questions are fine to ask in the GIS Chat Room.